# Creating a java program with geotools to load a shapefile, select a feature based on user input, and then create a new shapefile with that selection

Tags: java, gis, shapefile, geotools

I'm writing a GUI program that gets user input about a parcel, asks what types of data they want to extract, and then loads a shapefile of the entire county, selects the parcel by parcel number (user input) and then creates a new shapefile of just that parcel, along with attributes of that parcel. Further development will include exporting the road and stream system near the parcel, within a bound outside the parcel line, and also will export a GeoTiff of the area along with contours from a DEM raster. Ideally I'd like to then export them to a DXF or DWG, but that's for the next version.

So far I've got the file system building going just fine, and the GUI is done. However, I am now having issues with the parcel selection and extraction from the larger shapefile. I am using some code for shapefile extract that I found in an Ian Turton post that cleaned up my code quite a bit for the creation of the new shapefile. However, it is exported as "null_shapefile" and does not get my feature written to it. I believe my code doesn't correctly extract the feature and store it in memory, or it could be in how I'm passing the data store to the code I pulled from Ian's stuff.

So here's the code that I'm currently using:

```
File inFile = new File("D:\\GIS_project\\HumCo_Parcels_10.19.22.shp");
File outFile = new File(dirPath + projNum + "_PARCEL.shp");

// Read
ShapefileDataStore inputDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore) FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(inFile);
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource()
            
String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
FeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);
            
Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("APN_12 = '" + projAPN + "'");
FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features = featureSource.getFeatures(filter);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are there any features in the collection?

Comment: Good question...how do I check? I'm loading an APN file for Humboldt County that includes all of the parcels in the County.

Edit: Could it be in how I'm filtering from the collection? I'm using the QGIS syntax, but do I need to use different syntax for GeoTools?